# Amazon S3 Permissions

Tags: amazon-s3

I need to have all my bucket files to be public for view. I have added view permissions to everyone at bucket properties in AWS console. But looks like after that I have to explicitly press "Make public" for the file. Why if I already have rights for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this policy to your bucket under the bucket's main preferences will allow global read access to all files in your bucket.  Replace YOURBUCKETNAME with the name of your bucket.  This will only allow downloading, not listing files or anything else.

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOURBUCKETNAME/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

For a starting point for more information see the following links.

- http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html
- http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?AccessPolicyLanguage_UseCases_s3_a.html
- http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/index.html?UsingIAMPolicies.html